# How do I strip whitespace from a string in OCaml?

Tags: string, ocaml

To learn the basics of OCaml, I'm solving one of the easy [facebook engineering puzzles](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=7) using it.  Essentially, I'd like to do something like the following Python code:

```
some_str = some_str.strip()
```

That is, I'd like to strip all of the whitespace from the beginning and the end.  I don't see anything obvious to do this in the OCaml [Str](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) library.  Is there any easy way to do this, or am I going to have to write some code to do it (which I wouldn't mind, but would prefer not to :) ).

Bear in mind that I'm limited to what's in the libraries that come with the OCaml distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about

```
let trim str =
  if str = "" then "" else
  let search_pos init p next =
    let rec search i =
      if p i then raise(Failure "empty") else
      match str.[i] with
      | ' ' | '\n' | '\r' | '\t' -> search (next i)
      | _ -> i
    in
    search init
  in
  let len = String.length str in
  try
    let left = search_pos 0 (fun i -> i >= len) (succ)
    and right = search_pos (len - 1) (fun i -> i < 0) (pred)
    in
    String.sub str left (right - left + 1)
  with
  | Failure "empty" -> ""
```

(Via [Code Codex](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Trim_whitespace_(spaces)_from_a_string#OCaml))

Comment: This question is at the top page of google. So for a quick lookup I'm putting an answer here. It is String.strip

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is uber-old, but I was just pondering the same thing and came-up with this (from toplevel):

```
let strip str = 
  let str = Str.replace_first (Str.regexp "^ +") "" str in
  Str.replace_first (Str.regexp " +$") "" str;;           
val strip : string -> string = <fun>
```

then

```
strip "   Hello, world!   ";;
- : string = "Hello, world!"
```

UPDATE:

As of 4.00.0, standard library includes [String.trim](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html#VALtrim)

Answer (score 7):

It is really a mistake to limit yourself to the standard library, since the standard ilbrary is missing a lot of things.  If, for example, you were to use Core, you could simply do:

```
open Core.Std

let x = String.strip "  foobar   "
let () = assert (x = "foobar")
```

You can of course look at the sources of Core if you want to see the implementation.  There is a similar function in ExtLib.

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke.  The rules say: "You are not guaranteed any libraries or plugins beyond what is part of the language/interpreter itself."  The distribution is INRIA OCaml.  Does Core fall under that category?

Comment: Core is not part of the standard library. It's a third-party library that extends the standard (like Extlib and Batteries). You can download it here: http://janestcapital.com/?q=node/13

Comment: String.strip is a function that will strip out what is defined by the 'drop' parameter - https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/v0.9/doc/base/Base/String/index.html#val-strip  By default, 'drop' is whitespaces/tabs/etc. so it will do the same as String.trim.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at the point when the other answers were given, version 4.00 was not out yet. Actually, in OCaml 4.00, there is a String.trim function in the [string module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html) to trim leading and trailing white spaces.

Alternatively, if you're restricted to an older version of OCaml, you may use this function that is shamelessly copied from the [source](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/string.ml#L90) of 4.00's string module.

```
let trim s =
  let is_space = function
    | ' ' | '\012' | '\n' | '\r' | '\t' -> true
    | _ -> false in
  let len = String.length s in
  let i = ref 0 in
  while !i < len && is_space (String.get s !i) do
    incr i
  done;
  let j = ref (len - 1) in
  while !j >= !i && is_space (String.get s !j) do
    decr j
  done;
  if !i = 0 && !j = len - 1 then
    s
  else if !j >= !i then
    String.sub s !i (!j - !i + 1)
  else
    ""
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this should work fine:

```
 #require "str";;

 let strip_string s =
   Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "[\r\n\t ]") "" s
```

Comment: if you provide an answer that requires extra compilation flags, then please include all the things needed to actually compile this code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the requirement for the Str module.

Answer (score 0):

Standard library's

```ml
String.trim
```

does exactly that.